# Reverse string from the most inner parentheses and delete the parentheses when reverse

Tags: java, string

I am practicing some coding in codefights.com. Now facing this problem.
A string consists of letters, punctuation marks, whitespace and brackets. 
the bracket will be like this (). The task is to reverse the strings contained in the 
each pair of matching parentheses, starting from the innermost pair. The result string
should not contain any parentheses. some example are as follows :

`input : "a(bc)de"
output : "acbde"`

`input : "a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q"
output : "apmnolkjihgfedcbq"`

`input : "abc(cba)ab(bac)c"
output : "abcabcabcabc"`

For the first 2 example my code works fine. But for the 3rd one it gives the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException as follows :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:872)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:72)
    at codefight.arcade.intro.level_3.ReverseParentheses.reverseParentheses(ReverseParentheses.java:45)
    at codefight.arcade.intro.level_3.ReverseParentheses.main(ReverseParentheses.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)`

Here is my code for the task >>>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc(cba)ab(bac)c";
    String outputString = reverseParentheses(s);

    System.out.print(outputString);
}

public static String reverseParentheses(String str) {

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(str);
    String prnth1 = "(";
    String prnth2 = ")";
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == prnth1.charAt(0)) {
            list1.add(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == prnth2.charAt(0)) {
            list2.add(i);
        }
    }

    Collections.reverse(list1);
    for (int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++) {
        int firstIndex = list1.get(i);
        int lastIndex = list2.get(i);
        String ascString = s.substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex);
        String reverseString = new StringBuilder(ascString).reverse().toString();
        s = new StringBuilder(s.toString().replace(s.substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex), reverseString));

    }
    s = new StringBuilder(s.toString().replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)",""));
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @JoeC thanks for your reply. It may be a silly logical mistake for which I am having IndexOutOfBounce error. I need help to build my logic here.

Comment: Perhaps, but Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.  Please spend some time in the debugger to find where the fault is, and if you cannot understand the reason for the fault, then feel free to ask about that.  (I would start by asking why `substring` is being called with an index of `-4`).